# If there are several Positions, then find only the main one, otherwise take another

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

```
+-------------+------------------+----------+---------------+--------------+
|Id           |EmployeePositionId|Date      |Time           |TypeEmployment|
+-------------+------------------+----------+---------------+--------------+
|4399         |4557              |2022-01-10|60             |0             |
|4399         |4557              |2022-01-10|480            |0             |
|4399         |4561              |2022-01-10|540            |1             |
|4399         |4559              |2022-01-10|540            |2             |
|2448         |3017              |2022-01-31|480            |0             |
|2448         |3017              |2022-01-28|480            |0             |
|3406         |3841              |2022-01-31|480            |1             |
|3406         |3841              |2022-01-28|480            |1             |
|3406         |3841              |2022-01-27|480            |1             |
|3406         |3841              |2022-01-26|480            |1             |
+-------------+------------------+----------+---------------+--------------+
```

Need to filter the records so that the employee mostly has only the position with the employment type 0.

I can't just do `where TypeEmployment = 0`, because it will cut off the employee with private face id 3406

But I would like to see him, because he does not have a position with type 0

However, the employee with PrivateFaceId 4399 has three positions: 4557, 4561, 4559 (with type 0, 1, 2 respectively) and I would like to filter out those entries that do not match type 0

This is something like coalesce for rows, not columns. Which takes those first positions with type 0, if they are not, then with type 1, if they are not, then with type 2

Finally, i would like to see:

```
+-------------+------------------+----------+---------------+--------------+
|Id           |EmployeePositionId|Date      |Time           |TypeEmployment|
+-------------+------------------+----------+---------------+--------------+
|4399         |4557              |2022-01-10|60             |0             |
|4399         |4557              |2022-01-10|480            |0             |
|2448         |3017              |2022-01-31|480            |0             |
|2448         |3017              |2022-01-28|480            |0             |
|3406         |3841              |2022-01-31|480            |1             |
|3406         |3841              |2022-01-28|480            |1             |
|3406         |3841              |2022-01-27|480            |1             |
|3406         |3841              |2022-01-26|480            |1             |
+-------------+------------------+----------+---------------+--------------+
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: you can use `UNION`, first query employees with Type=0, and second query to get employees with min(Type) !=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order positions within the id as needed, take the first one

```
select *
from (
    select * 
       , row_number() over(partition by Id order by TypeEmployment) rn
    from mytable
) t
where rn=1
```

Use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()` if all positions with the same top `TypeEmployment` are required.

Comment: Exactly! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions.

The first uses a `group by`:

```
select * from Table1 where
("Id", "TypeEmployment") in
(select
 "Id", min("TypeEmployment")
from Table1
group by "Id")
order by 5, 2 desc, 4, 3 desc
;
```

The second uses a window function `min`:

```
WITH subq as (select
 *, min("TypeEmployment") over (partition by "Id") mini
from Table1)
select 
  "Id",
  "EmployeePositionId",
  "Date",
  "Time",
  "TypeEmployment"
from
  subq
where
  "TypeEmployment"="mini"
order by 5, 2 desc, 4, 3 desc
;
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("Id" int, "EmployeePositionId" int, "Date" timestamp, "Time" int, "TypeEmployment" int)
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    ("Id", "EmployeePositionId", "Date", "Time", "TypeEmployment")
VALUES
    (4399, 4557, '2022-01-10 00:00:00', 60, 0),
    (4399, 4557, '2022-01-10 00:00:00', 480, 0),
    (4399, 4561, '2022-01-10 00:00:00', 540, 1),
    (4399, 4559, '2022-01-10 00:00:00', 540, 2),
    (2448, 3017, '2022-01-31 00:00:00', 480, 0),
    (2448, 3017, '2022-01-28 00:00:00', 480, 0),
    (3406, 3841, '2022-01-31 00:00:00', 480, 1),
    (3406, 3841, '2022-01-28 00:00:00', 480, 1),
    (3406, 3841, '2022-01-27 00:00:00', 480, 1),
    (3406, 3841, '2022-01-26 00:00:00', 480, 1)
;
```

Output:

| Id | EmployeePositionId | Date | Time | TypeEmployment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4399 | 4557 | 2022-01-10T00:00:00Z | 60 | 0 |
| 4399 | 4557 | 2022-01-10T00:00:00Z | 480 | 0 |
| 2448 | 3017 | 2022-01-31T00:00:00Z | 480 | 0 |
| 2448 | 3017 | 2022-01-28T00:00:00Z | 480 | 0 |
| 3406 | 3841 | 2022-01-31T00:00:00Z | 480 | 1 |
| 3406 | 3841 | 2022-01-28T00:00:00Z | 480 | 1 |
| 3406 | 3841 | 2022-01-27T00:00:00Z | 480 | 1 |
| 3406 | 3841 | 2022-01-26T00:00:00Z | 480 | 1 |